# Adjectival Phrases- "accessory before the fact" vs "accessory after the fact"

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, legalese, adjective-phrases

> What is the difference between ***accessory before the fact*** and ***accessory after the fact***?

Although I knew the individual meanings of them but unable to differentiate them from each other. Google says that both are similar per my comprehension.

Answer (score 3):

These are legal terms, and *fact* is employed in its original Latin sense of *thing done, deed*—it designates the criminal act to which one is "accessory"

To be an accessory *before the fact* means to assist the criminal before the crime is committed: to contribute in some way to performing the crime. To be an accessory *after the fact* means to assist the criminal after the crime is committed: typically, to help the criminal escape detection or arrest.